# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - iOS - Error during Login - "errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST"

Tags: ios, iphone, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have tried using both xcode simulator and install the .ipa file directly to the device (through iTunes) and got the connection error. This is the detail:

Mar 27 20:33:30 --- last message repeated 5 times ---
Mar 27 20:33:30 myMBPro Inspection[10213]: ERROR: {"textMsg":"Your user name and password could not be validated. Connect to the server and try again."}
Mar 27 20:33:30 myMBPro Inspection[10213]: nw_interface_create_with_index refusing to create an interface with index 4294967295 too high (>=2147483647)
Mar 27 20:33:30 myMBPro Inspection[10213]: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
Mar 27 20:33:30 myMBPro Inspection[10213]: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
Mar 27 20:33:30 myMBPro Inspection[10213]: Cancel processing requested
Mar 27 20:33:31 myMBPro Inspection[10213]: ERROR: {"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service is currently not available."}

I did install SSL on the app server that hosts Appcenter & MaximoAnywhere (https://maximodev:9443/MaximoAnywhere  https://maximodev:9443/appcenteradmin/installers.html)

I follow this IBM documentation:
www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_installing_the_client_on_a_ios_mob.html

Is there any other configuration files need to be set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your device doesn't trust the certificate that you're using on the MobileFirst server.  Can you check your certificate trust list on the iOS device?